# Crystal Reports 8 for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

Is there any way we can run the Crystal Reports 8 on Visual Studio 2013.
I have a Vb.Net Project which was built using VS2008 + Crystal Reports 8.

Now I am running Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition. but the project is not opening is because of Crystal Report References. I know there won't be any! for that ancient Crystal Report version but trying for a luck? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

To integrate Crystal Reports development int Visual Studio 2013 you must use "SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio".

It does NOT support Express Editions of any version of Visual Studio .NET.

### [You can get it here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) (choose Install Executable - Support Pack 12)

Single .rpt files can be edited with new Crystal Reports.

If your project was created with older Crystal Report version, you can update assembly version into your configuration file.

```
 <assemblies>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

Comment: I already have the latest version of Crystal Reports for my visual studio(Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2013 Package). but my problem is with Crystal Reports 8(A very old one)

Comment: No. Your problem is in Visual Studio because the project is not opening in Visual Studio. Can you post your errors? I think you should change manually references to CrystalDecisions DLLs, as shown in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend running Crystal Reports 8 reports with VS Crystal runtime engine. You should run only Crystal XI or later reports with the later runtime engines. The whole IT world has changed since Crystal Reports 8, especially the way Crystal Reports connects to databases. Note, some of your Crystal Reports 8 report WILL work, but I can promise that it won't be all of them.