# Crystal Report For Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to integrate Crystal Report with my VB.NET Project. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 express Edition as an IDE.

After an exhaustive search, I was ending with the same results that it's **not supportable for any EXPRESS EDITIONS**.

Can anyone please tell me a work-around for this? I **don't want to change the IDE**.

Thanks is advance.

Reference for the unsupportablity: [Crystal Reports 8 for Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269752/crystal-reports-8-for-visual-studio-2013)

Thanks in advance.